# Converting to decimal algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I was studying an algorithm which converts binary to decimal and I stumbled across a weird problem for me. The algorithm is supposed to work the same in every platform, but it returns different results on another computer. It returns 7 from 10110 which is 22. Code:

```java
public class Main {
    
    public static int convertToDecimal(String binary) {
        int conversion = 1; 
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= binary.length(); i++) {
            if (binary.charAt(binary.length() - i) == '1') {
                result += conversion;
                conversion *= 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertToDecimal("10110");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubling the `conversion` variable should be placed outside the `if` block.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= binary.length(); i++) {
    if (binary.charAt(binary.length() - i) == '1') {
        result += conversion;
    }
    conversion *= 2; // or conversion <<= 1;
}
```

The built-in method with `Integer.parseInt` should be preferred:

```
return Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int convertToDecimal(String binary) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            result += Math.pow(2, binary.length() - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this sould work